# Windows 10 not able to connect to samba drive in Gateway

Tags: linux, windows, samba, windows-10

I have connected a USB drive on my Router and tried to access the same using `\\192.168.1.1` from my windows 10 machine.

The drive simply isn't loading and while capturing the LAN interface logs I'm able to see that there is no response from the server for the setup AndX Request sent from my Windows 10 latptop.

Could this be due to any authentication configuration conflicts between windows 10 and linux?
I have also enclosed the wireshark snippet for your reference.The access seems to be working fine from Windows 7 machine.Previously i also had some issue when the samba server was access controlled with Credentials.Then I had to disable the policy negotiation in windows 7 to access the drive.

`“Policy Negotiation:`

```
Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Local Policies->Security Options
```

`Find the policy:`

```
Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)
```

If this is `enabled`, change it to `Disabled`. Be sure and restart your machine for the change to take effect! (**Pressing the "Apply" button in the Policy Editor after the change is made is not sufficient**)
“

[image]

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: Not sure if i fully understand. So you are trying to access a samba share from a linux system on the same network? or you are trying to access a USB drive connected to  your router?  Do you have any non-windows 10 machines that can connect using the method you are using as a test base? or is the windows 10 machine the only machine you have access to?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I'm trying to access the USB drive connected to a Gateway which is running on Linux.The USB drive is mounted as SAMBA share to the Gateway.I'm successfully able to connect to the drive from a windows 7 machine but not from windows 10.

Comment: I tried the same scenario using a local user account and then the client is able to establish the session but when i tried the same using an e-mail account then the host is not able to connect

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, found the solution in windows control panel - user accounts - manage your credentials - windows credentials. Add the network path, user account, and password as a windows credential here. Worked for me anyway. Good luck.